# The function with WITH is throwing an error in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, function

I am trying to put some statements into the following function.

```
create or replace function public.raster_data_extraction(
    resolution integer, 
    pixel_size double precision, 
    upper_x double precision, 
    upper_y double precision,
    out centroid geometry, 
    out b1 double precision,
    out b2 double precision,
    out b3 double precision,
    out b4 double precision,
    out b5 double precision,
    out b6 double precision,
    out b7 double precision)
RETURNS SETOF record
 LANGUAGE sql
 volatile STRICT
AS $function$


--- create fishnet
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS public.grid_function;
CREATE TABLE public.grid_function AS
SELECT *
--                    nrow, ncol, xsize (km), ysize (km), x0, y0
FROM ST_CreateFishnet(resolution, resolution, pixel_size, pixel_size, upper_x, upper_y) AS cells;
-- set srid
ALTER TABLE public.grid_function ALTER COLUMN geom TYPE geometry(Polygon,32632) USING ST_SetSRID(geom,32632);
-- drop old and create new index
drop index if exists grid_function_id; 
CREATE INDEX grid_function_id ON public.grid_function USING gist (geom);

-- raster to vector data
WITH raster_data AS (
  SELECT ST_PixelAsPolygons(rast.rast,1) band1, ST_PixelAsPolygons(rast.rast,2) band2,
         ST_PixelAsPolygons(rast.rast,3) band3, ST_PixelAsPolygons(rast.rast,4) band4,
         ST_PixelAsPolygons(rast.rast,5) band5, ST_PixelAsPolygons(rast.rast,6) band6,
         ST_PixelAsPolygons(rast.rast,7) band7
  
  FROM grid_function g , public.t32ulc_entire_tile rast
  WHERE ST_Intersects(rast.rast, g.geom)),

raster_bands as
(select  ST_Centroid((band1).geom) as centroid, 
        (band1).val as b1, 
        (band2).val as b2,
        (band3).val as b3,
        (band4).val as b4,
        (band5).val as b5,
        (band6).val as b6,
        (band7).val as b7

from raster_data)

select * from raster_bands;

$function$
;
```

What function does:

1. creates grid table with the specified parameters
2. using the created grid table it should extract data from raster table using the ST_Intersect rule. The grid table and raster data geometrically intersects.

The function created with no error. But execution of the following SQL query returns error.

```
select * from raster_data_extraction (128, 1.28, 300000, 5690220);
```

the error is

```
SQL Error [42P01]: ERROR: relation with OID 76694740 does not exist
  Where: SQL function "raster_data_extraction" statement 6
```

Execution of statements with same parameters outside the function works perfectly.
What is wrong here?

```
select * from pg_class where oid = 76694740;
```

returned

```
oid     |relname      |relnamespace|reltype |reloftype|relowner|relam|relfilenode|reltablespace|relpages|reltuples|relallvisible|reltoastrelid|relhasindex|relisshared|relpersistence|relkind|relnatts|relchecks|relhasrules|relhastriggers|relhassubclass|relrowsecurity|relforcerowsecurity|relispopulated|relreplident|relispartition|relrewrite|relfrozenxid|relminmxid|relacl|reloptions|relpartbound|
--------+-------------+------------+--------+---------+--------+-----+-----------+-------------+--------+---------+-------------+-------------+-----------+-----------+--------------+-------+--------+---------+-----------+--------------+--------------+--------------+-------------------+--------------+------------+--------------+----------+------------+----------+------+----------+------------+
76694740|grid_function|        2200|76694742|        0|61901349|    2|   76694746|            0|     316|  16384.0|            0|     76694749|true       |false      |p             |r      |       3|        0|false      |false         |false         |false         |false              |true          |d           |false         |         0|50805732    |1         |NULL  |NULL      |            |
```

Comment: Did this happen on the first run of the function or on a subsequent run?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver on the first run

Comment: Hmm. 1) Does `select * from pg_class where oid = 76694653` return anything? 2) I have seen caching issues with `plpgsql` that where solved with [Dynamic SQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-EXECUTING-DYN) e.g. `EXECUTE ...`. 3) Why not create `TEMPORARY` table as it is going to be thrown away anyway?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver 1. get an error `SQL Error [42P01]: ERROR: relation with OID 76694740 does not exist
  Where: SQL function "raster_data_extraction" statement 6` and select query with 76694740 returned smth and relname = 'grid_function'. 2. I will review the issue. 3. can you please provide your version with temporary and execute?

Comment: What does `returned smth` mean?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver please have a look at the bottom of the question. I edited

Comment: 1) Where are you seeing the error? In other words what client are you running this in? 2) Does the function return its data?

Comment: @AdrianKlaver I am using dbeaver to execute the query. 2. execution of the function with parameters returns the above mentioned error.

Comment: 1) I am not a fan of dbeaver it seems to create as many problems as it solves. Run the code in `psql` to double check. 2) But does it also return the data? Again run in `psql` to verify.